Time travel, with compensation for planetary position and velocity
Can anyone recognise a book about someone, maybe a family or group of friends, who make a time machine, and then travel in it. It's more of a vehicle, and there's a load of conversation about how the hardest thing was allowing for the different positions and velocities of the solar system and planet(s?) at different times (and I seem to recall that they used that for propelling the machine in normal non-time travelling situations). The vehicle was likely space-worthy as I think they travelled to space, or at least the atmosphere, at some point.
I want to say that the vehicle was called something like the Skylark, or the Robin, or something; maybe I'm crazy but I remember it being built in a workshop or garage at his home, and being red, and relatively small.
Sorry there's not much to go on.

It's not Heinlein's "The Number of the Beast --" or The Pursuit of the Pankera, though there's some similarities.

Tvtrope about this issue

@JeffZeitlin no, that's not it, thanks. Those DO look interesting, though...

"The Stars my Destination": Teleportation moves you but doesn't affect your motion vector, which limits distance on Earths surface to maybe 25km.

@gnasher729 that was also done in Impulse, by Steven Gould, but taken further.

E.E. "Doc" Smith's Skylark series might be a reasonable fit but it's not a time machine.
The first in the series The Skylark of Space.

At the beginning of the story, Seaton accidentally discovers a workable space drive in combining pure copper with a newly discovered [fictional] element "X" (suggested to be a stable transactinide element in the platinum group) in solution. Having failed to re-create the effect, Seaton realizes that the missing component is a field generated by DuQuesne's particle accelerator, and thereafter sets up a business with his millionaire friend, Martin Crane, to build a spaceship.

Navigation is complicated until they develop..

an "Object Compass" that once locked on an object, always points toward that object.


Thanks, but that's not it. I wondered about those, I even have them, but I don't believe that's it. Yes, I may have merged the ship name in (hence my uncertainty about it in the original question) but I'm pretty darn sure that's not what I'm remembering.

You may be thinking of Heinlein's 1980 The Number of the Beast featuring four people (a father, his daughter, the daughter's new husband and a woman who soon marries the father) who enhance a flying car (in this story, a common kind of vehicle) with a device that allows them to travel in time and space (and into other dimensions). They spend some time learning how to compensate for the motion of the Earth (and other planets when they are going to other planets). The flying car/space-time traveling device is called "Gay Deceiver."
I don't have an electronic copy of Number of the Beast, but I do have a copy of The Pursuit of the Pankera, an alternate version of the novel (with much the same text in many places).  Here's where they talk about the motion of the planets, etc.:

“...Captain, we did not aim for Mars.”
“I know. I was chicken.”
“No, sir, you were properly cautious. We aimed for a specific point in
empty space. We transited to that point … but not with Mars’ proper
motion. With that of the solar system, yes. With Earth’s motions
subtracted; that is in the program. But we are a short distance ahead
of Mars in its orbit … so it is rushing toward us.”
“Does that mean we can never land on any planet but Earth?”
“Not at all. Any vector can be included in the program—either before
or after transition, translation or rotation. Any subsequent change in
motion is taken into account by the inertial integrator.


Argh. Just noticed the comment that it wasn't the Heinlein - a comment I probably read in August and forgot
